# Factor variables in r

Tags: r, statistics, glm, categorical-data

I have a dataset including three factor variables in r and the output of my glm model consistently gives estimates for each individual categorical value. I tried to correct this by using the as.numeric command as shown below and I used the factor command in the glm model but I still got the same output.

```
as.numeric(levels(Make))[as.integer(Make)]
as.numeric(levels(Zone))[as.integer(Zone)]
as.numeric(levels(Kilometres))[as.integer(Kilometres)]
```

For the glm model I opted for a gamma distribution using the default link function.

```
 Gamma = glm(perd ~ factor(Kilometres) + factor(Zone) + Bonus + factor(Make) + Insured, 
      family = Gamma(link = "inverse"))
```

I have no idea how I should change my code such that it gives regression estimates for the entire variable. Any ideas on that?

Comment: you mean you want the intersect of the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't convert your categorical variable into numeric variables - this will create a very different model [your attempts would not have worked anyway]
2. There is no such thing as a "regression" estimate for the entire variable. If a categorical variable has n categories, the standard approach will create n-1 indicator variables, each of which will have a estimate.
3. You want to test the impact of dropping a categorical variable.

The very first example in the help file for `glm` gives an example where you use `anova` to perform the appropriate hypothesis tests regarding the impact of dropping the variable [an analysis of Deviance]

```
# In your case
anova(Gamma)

# or
drop1(Gamma)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would a stepAIC also be useful when testing whether I should drop a variable?